# updating rhythmbox failed

Tags: update-manager, rhythmbox

I updated my rhythmbox2.99.1 to 3.0.1 manually using the terminal but still the update manager tries to update rhythmbox's core and ends up in `update failed, report this problem` and when i try to report, the applet displays `This Problem cannot be reported. This is not an official Ubuntu package. Please remove any third party packages and try again`. I am using ubuntu13.10 I am a new linux user

Comment: how did you updated rhythmbox from 2.99.1 to 3.0.1?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: i used-
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jacob/media,
sudo apt-get update,
sudo apt-get install rhythmbox.

Comment: jacob's PPA for Ubuntu 13.04,use fossfreedom's ppa for Ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before installing Rhythmbox 3.0, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open terminal. Remove the default installation:

```
sudo apt-get purge rhythmbox rhythmbox-plugins
```

Then run below commands one by one:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fossfreedom/rhythmbox
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rhythmbox
```